# Triggering the ":active" pseudo-class on a touchscreen

Tags: html, google-chrome, touch, touchscreen

I'm currently developing a JavaScript application which will be deployed on a touchscreen kiosk running Chrome in kiosk mode.

I've noticed that when I use a mouse to click the buttons on the interface, the styles applied by the ":active" pseudo class is visible when the mouse is down. My problem is that the same button triggered by touching the screen does not trigger the active state.

Is there a way to make a touch event behave the same way as a mouse click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the CSS :active pseudo-class isn't working, you'll probably need to use DOM events.

Do the "mousedown" and "mouseup" events work with touchscreens? Assuming they do, you could try something like this:

```
addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
    if (event.target.setAttribute) {
        event.target.setAttribute("data-active", "");
    }
}, true);

addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
    if (event.target.removeAttribute) {
        event.target.removeAttribute("data-active");
    }
}, true);
```

Then within your CSS, replace :active with [data-active], like so:

```
div[data-active] {
    /* blah blah */
}
```

I don't think this will work quite the same... you may need to do some trickery to get child elements to work correctly, for instance.

Comment: This is a good approach, though I think the problem I have now is that mousedown and mouseup are both triggered when the touch ends, so I need to find a touchstart event.

Comment: I've marked this as accepted, though I have amended the code to apply a "selected" class rather than add the data-active attribute. Thanks!

Now to find out why Chrome isn't registering ontouchstart events!

Comment: The problem with using classes is that it makes it harder when an element has more than one class at the same time... using attributes is easier, in my experience. Using classes is fine too, whatever works for you.